# @autoreleasepool block in loop dose not reduce memory peak

Tags: ios, nsautoreleasepool

I was told that @autoreleasepool block in loop can reduce the peak of memory usage until I do a test. The test device is iPhone 6s with iOS 11.4.1.

my code:

```
@implementation BigMemObj{
    NSMutableArray *_mutArr;
}

-(instancetype)init{
    if(self = [super init]){
        _mutArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1024*1024*30];
        for(int i = 0; i < 1024*1024*30; i++){
            [_mutArr addObject:@(i)];
        }
    }

    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10000; i++){
        @autoreleasepool {
            BigMemObj *mem = [[BigMemObj alloc] init];
        }
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10000; i++){
           BigMemObj *mem = [[BigMemObj alloc] init];
    }
}
```

I run both test 34 seconds, in test 1, the highest memory usage is 458M, but in the test 2 the highest memory usage is 362M. and both test have a triangle shape.

with @autoreleaspool block

[image]

without @autoreleaspool block
[image]

Did the autoreleasepool implementation changed? or the compiler dose some optimization?

Thank You！

Comment: ARC automatically release object after completion of block in which they are being used, so there is no need of using @autoreleasepool manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all looks normal actually. The growth you are seeing is this part:

```
_mutArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1024*1024*30];
for(int i = 0; i < 1024*1024*30; i++){
    [_mutArr addObject:@(i)];
}
```

So here you are adding your numbers to an array `_mutArr` and you are adding `1024*1024*30` of them. When this loop finishes the `_mutArr` is valid and full, it retains all of those numbers. This would not even be changed by adding another autorelease pool within this loop because your array will not let those numbers be released.

Now after this constructor is being called you have

```
@autoreleasepool {
    BigMemObj *mem = [[BigMemObj alloc] init];
}
```

so autorelease pool will be drained in this moment releasing all the numbers inside `BigMemObj` instance `mem` and your memory is back to normal.

You might expect that your application should keep growing in memory without the call to `@autoreleasepool`. But there is no change at all if you remove that call. The reason for that is that none of your code uses autorelease pool at all. What your code translates to (non-ARC) is:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10000; i++){
    @autoreleasepool {
        BigMemObj *mem = [[BigMemObj alloc] init];
        [mem release];
    }
}
[arr release];
```

But you would need your `autoreleasepool` only if it was

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10000; i++){
    @autoreleasepool {
        BigMemObj *mem = [[[BigMemObj alloc] init] autorelease];
    }
}
[arr release];
```

**To have a situation where autorelease pool is needed:**

```
NSMutableArray *allBigValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"profile.png"];

for(int i = 0; i<100000; i++){
    @autoreleasepool {
        [allBigValues addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];
        [allBigValues removeAllObjects];
    }
}
```

If in this code you remove the autorelease pool it will grow in memory until the loop ends. The reason for this is because `imageWithContentsOfFile` is using autorelease pool and all the images produced by this method will only be released after the pool is drained. Since the main pool will not be released inside the loop we need to create another one.

Bottom line this code works nicely but as soon as you remove the `@autoreleasepool` part it will start growing in memory and probably crash you application.

**Note 1:** You need to add image `profile.png` into your app for this code to work (just drag it among source files, not the assets).

**Note 2:** We use "drain" where it comes to pools because this used to be the name of the method you needed to call when you wanted for the pool to remove it's objects. This is how it used to be:

```
for(int i = 0; i<100000; i++){
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [allBigValues addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];
    [allBigValues removeAllObjects];
    [pool drain];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation Matic Oblak. So the global @autoreleasepool in the main function generated by Xcode is for legacy, right?

Comment: @user1764186 No, the global one is still needed. And local ones are sometimes still needed. It is your specific case that does not need that. I am not sure which methods still use autoreleased objects but those that do would need an internal autorelease pool. It is sometimes hard to find/create examples for this due to compiler being able to optimize your code.

Comment: @user1764186 Please check my edit. I added an example where you need to use an extra autorelease pool and some extra explanations.

Comment: Your explanation is very clear. Thanks a lot! After tried your example,  I found another case: NSString create by stringWithFormat:  generate autorelease objects too.